# Find fields and tables that can make a report blank

Tags: sql-server

Consider the situation where I have a report(Stored Procedure) in SQL Server. I would like to know which fields and tables need to be populated in my database for that report to return rows. For a small procedure like this:

```
Create Procedure dbo.getWorkOrders @status nvarchar(10)
Select Member.Member_Name, Member.Member_ID, WorkOrder.Technician_ID, WorkOrder.Status
From Member Inner Join WorkOrder 
   on WorkOrder.Member_ID = Member.Member_ID
Where
   WorkOrder.Status like @status
```

For the example above, I would define the required data by looking at inner joins and items in the where clause. In this example, there must be rows on the Member table with Member_ID's, there must also be rows on WorkOrder with Member_ID's and statuses. I'm not concerned if the procedure returns blank because the user enters a status that doesn't exist on the WorkOrder table, but I am concerned if the WorkOrder table was loaded rows that have no status, or if no rows were loaded for Member or WorkOrder.

To put it another way, a routine task for me is to find out what data needs to be loaded in a warehouse so that we can test the stored procedures. I'm currently doing this manually as I described in the example above, but there are many reports and tables so it's a difficult process. I would like to automate this part of my job. Does something like this already exist? If I'm going to code it, how should I start?

I was thinking about writing something in Python to extract the Inner Join and Where clauses, but if it makes sense to make a stored procedure to do this in SQL Server I would prefer that.

Comment: If your having these issues it is a database design issue that would need to be fixed.  Dont let users enter text strings for data make them select IDs or values only that exist in your lookup table for example.  And create PK and FKs that require data to be in each table on insert for your joins.

Comment: The problem would not exist if the person developing the SP would have bothered to write automated tests as well.

Comment: @Brad To add some more clarity, it's often the case that the end user is just running a report with no filters. Before we get to UAT, we have to import many different data sets. The end user might specify which reports they want and I would like a program where I can just enter the procedure name and get a list of all the fields and rows that require input for rows to be returned, so I can quickly figure out what data needs to be imported.

Comment: @RuudHelderman It's not that simple because we have different end users on different databases that use specific reports. It's normal to have empty tables depending on what they want.

Comment: @rallen "(...) data needs to be loaded in a warehouse so that we can __test__ the stored procedures." Part of writing an automated test is supplying test data. That should be the responsibility of the author of the code under test (in this case a stored procedure). Unless I totally misjudged the situation, and you have end users writing their own stored procedures.

Comment: You seem to assume that your report sources are very simple tsql queries. IME most of the really useful report sources (from a business perspective) will often have very, VERY complex logic. IMO your goal to analyze the logic and then fabricate the data needed is going to require far more work than you realize. I think you overlook the complexity of all the "other" relationships with tables not directly used by the report that will also require data.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Ahhhh, yeah I get what you're saying now. It hadn't occurred to me to check for front-end testing of the procedures. I'm going to check on this, but I'm guessing that those test cases won't include the minimum set of data to execute the report. It would probably be a superset of the minimum to cover UI testing. I'm just looking for a starting point when a user sends me CSV files and they tell me which report they need, so I can quickly verify that I have at least the minimum set of data.

Comment: @SMor yeah I agree that the actual reports are complicated. For example, procedures calling procedures, dynamics T-SQL, etc. It's very time consuming for me to answer the question, "Are these CSV files enough data for us to use this report?". I'm trying to speed that up here

Comment: "Are these CSV files enough data for us to use this report?" So I guess you need a list of _tables_ referenced by the SP, to figure out whether or not a given set of CSV files is complete, right? A really dirty trick would be: _drop_ every table that is _not_ covered by a CSV file. Then execute the SP. If it goes boom, then the set was incomplete.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Yeah that would be a good starting point. These reports reference many tables though, so that list would probably be very long. Would be good to be able to sort it down further by excluding left joins(optional), Unions (Also optional), etc.

Comment: I'm curious now as to what tools you're trying to use to test these procedures. Messing around with CSV files sounds sub-optimal. e.g.: tSQLt Test should supply all of the functionality you need to write tests for these procedures, including the ability to load data into tables for procs under test in test setup procs, fake called procedures, etc..